# How do I get to the update settings window when the system is up-to-date?

Tags: updates

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I would like to get to the "additional drivers" menu, which I can normally access by clicking the "settings" button when running the software updater.

However, I've been a good computer user today, and have applied all available updates. Now when I run the software updater, I get this:

[image: Window showing an "The software on this computer is up to date" message]

Why on earth is there no settings button here, and how can I get to the update settings menu now?

Comment: You can launch it from a terminal window with `software-properties-gtk`.

Comment: @mikewhatever Cool, that at least got me there. Really strange the menu itself doesn't have a button for it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to launch the "**Software & Updates**" application instead of the "*Software Updater*" application. Search for "Software & Updates" in *Activities* overview and launch it.

Alternatively, as [@mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever) pointed out in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088711/how-do-i-get-to-the-update-settings-window-when-the-system-is-up-to-date#comment1791312_1088711), you can launch the application by running the `software-properties-gtk` command in Terminal.